# TypeError: (0 , scrapeSpotifyData_1.scrapeSpotifyData) is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, node.js, typescript, express

I am attempting to make an endpoint for post requests that calls a function, scrapeSpotifyData:

```
const scrapeSpotifyData = async () => {
   // this code all works fine when I manually call scrapeSpotifyData()
}

export { scrapeSpotifyData };
```

I have my API endpoint set up in api/spotify.ts:

```
import express from "express";
import { Song } from "../models/Song";
import { scrapeSpotifyData } from "../scrapers/scrapeSpotifyData";

const spotifyRouter = express.Router();

// Endpoint to trigger scraping of Spotify data
spotifyRouter.post("/scrape", async (req, res) => {
    try {
        console.log("inside post request to /spotify/scrape, about to call scrapeSpotifyData")
        await scrapeSpotifyData();
        res.status(200).json({ message: "Spotify data scraped successfully" });
    } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error scraping Spotify data:", error);
        res.status(500).json({ error: "Failed to scrape Spotify data" });
    }
});
```

And this code from api/index.ts may be relevant too:

```
import express from "express";
import { spotifyRouter } from "./spotify";

const apiRoutes = express.Router();

apiRoutes.use("/spotify", spotifyRouter);

export { apiRoutes };
```

I make the request within a React component here:

```
const handleScrapeData = async () => {
      console.log("inside handleScrapeData")
        try {
            const response = await fetch("http://localhost:8080/api/spotify/scrape", {
                method: "POST",
            });

            if (response.ok) {
                // If the scraping was successful, trigger a refetch of the Spotify data
                await fetchData();
            } else {
                throw new Error("Failed to scrape data");
            }
        } catch (error) {
            console.error("Error scraping data:", error);
        }
    };
```

But I am getting this error:

```
Error scraping Spotify data: TypeError: (0 , scrapeSpotifyData_1.scrapeSpotifyData) is not a function
    at /Users/me/Documents/GitHub/streaming-stats/server/src/api/spotify.ts:12:32
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Users/me/Documents/GitHub/streaming-stats/server/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at next (/Users/me/Documents/GitHub/streaming-stats/server/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:144:13)
    at Route.dispatch (/Users/me/Documents/GitHub/streaming-stats/server/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:114:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Users/me/Documents/GitHub/streaming-stats/server/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at /Users/me/Documents/GitHub/streaming-stats/server/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:284:15
    at Function.process_params (/Users/me/Documents/GitHub/streaming-stats/server/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:346:12)
    at next (/Users/me/Documents/GitHub/streaming-stats/server/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:280:10)
    at Function.handle (/Users/me/Documents/GitHub/streaming-stats/server/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:175:3)
    at router (/Users/me/Documents/GitHub/streaming-stats/server/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:47:12)
```

The message as well as some other StackOverflow posts suggest it's an issue with the way the function is imported/exported, but I have tried many things such as default vs not, arrow function vs normal function, import {x} from "" vs import x from "" etc and all give the same error. Any help appreciated :)